# What were the Romulans doing prior to "The Neutral Zone"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the *Next Generation* episode *The Neutral Zone* the Romulans are introduced to the viewers. Towards the end of the episode one of the Romulans mentions that they had been busy up until now, but that they are now back.

> TEBOK
>   Captain Picard, because your actions are those of a thoughtful man who is neither rash nor easily provoked, I tell you this. **More urgent matters have caused our absence**, and witness the results. Outposts destroyed, evidence of the Federation everywhere. We have been negligent, but no more.

What were these "more urgent matters" that Tebok mentioned? Was this ever covered officially?

Comment: They discovered Stack Overflow.

Comment: The started reading the ST:TNG TV Tropes page.

Comment: They were provoking the borg.  Which is what destroyed all the outposts.

Comment: @Zoredache According to what source?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Actually that comment may make the most sense, if you consider the [Narada](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Narada) from ST'09 (and more so if you consider STO as canon). It is conceivable that the Romulans were trying to get Borg tech that far back.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart, no source really, purely  speculation.   I just know that [The Neutral Zone](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Neutral_Zone_(episode)) was meant to be the first episode of three introducing the borg, but then the writers strike happened.  I kind of expected the borg to be part of the reason.

Comment: According to Star Trek: Countdown, that is exactly what happened, Romulan intelligence agency "Tal shiar" reverse-engineered Borg technology and applied it to the Narada.

Comment: @Zoredache The Romulans are portrayed in *The Neutral Zone* as being as clueless as Starfleet as to the cause of the attacks. I doubt they were provoking the Borg, and then pretending to be ignorant to the Federation.

Comment: @Keen Romulans may have been known to be duplicitous, on occasion.

Comment: They were dealing with a Tribble infestation.  Took them 40 years to eradicate them.

Comment: @BBlake More likely, if they got their hands on Tribbles they would use them to bring the Klingon Empire to ts knees.

Comment: Seriously now, you say "In the Next Generation episode The Neutral Zone the Romulans are introduced to the viewers", but they were actually introduced in the OST: [Balance of Terror](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Balance_of_Terror_(episode%29)

Comment: @MrLister Introduced to the TNG viewers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of the books and games deal lightly with the time period between the Treaty of Algeron and *The Neutral Zone,* but there isn't anything solid in the tv shows or movies that discuss it.  We do have references to certain events, such as the massacre at Khitomer, the cloning of Picard, stealing B4 from Soong's lab, and so forth but that's about it.  So there really isn't anything in canon which covers it.  Probably the result of the writers strike interrupting the intended story arc that *The Neutral Zone* was supposed to start.  That's probably a good thing anyway because, as I understand it, the original plan was to have the Borg completely wipe out the Romulan race after the events of that episode.

As presented in some of the RPG game modules by Last Unicorn, during much of the early part of the that time period the Romulans were expanding their empire in directions away from the Klingons and Federation, where they didn't have much resistance.  As a result they came across a race known as the Taurhai Unity and war erupted.  There was a video game that depicted a rogue Vulcan raising an army and attacking various Romulan bases and worlds as well.  One or two of the novels also deal with a couple of coups that occured during that time, so civil war was also part of the flow of events.  And as I recall, a couple of the comics also dealt with some events right around the time of their return.